# error: prototype for a class does not match any class - inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

I am trying to debug my program and see if it will run ok and I keep getting errors on all my constructors inheriting the superclass's constructor. All .h files for my subclasses give the same error. Can you explain and help me?

ERROR:
main.cpp:41: error: no matching function for call to ‘RandomRobot::RandomRobot(int, int&)’

RandomRobot.h:10: note: candidates are: RandomRobot::RandomRobot()
RandomRobot.h:7: note:                 RandomRobot::RandomRobot(const RandomRobot&)

One of my robots:

**RandomRobot.h"**

```
#ifndef RANDOMROBOT_H
#define RANDOMROBOT_H
#include "robotRace.h"

using namespace std;

class RandomRobot : public robotRace {

    public:
      RandomRobot();
      int Rposition(int, int);
      void print();
      int getRan();

    protected:

};

#endif
```

**RandomRobot.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "RandomRobot.h"

using namespace std;

RandomRobot :: RandomRobot() : robotRace(){

//initial position of robot will be placed in row 3. position 0 is 'X' track variable
// position 1 is for a different robot so next position which is 2 is where RandomRobot is
    track[2][0] = 'R';


}

// 20% : forward 1
// 30% : forward 2
//35% : don't move
// 15% : forward 6
int RandomRobot :: Rposition(int rows, int columns){
    int place =0;
    srand(time(NULL));
    int val= rand() % 100;

    if (val > 15 || val < 20)// 20%
      place = 1;
    else if (val > 20 || val <30) //30%
      place = 2;
    else if (val> 30 || val <35)// 35%
      place = 0;
    else if (val < 15)// 15%
      place = 6;

    int movement =+ place;
    cout <<"R Robot has moved: " << movement << " spaces."<<endl;
    track[rows][columns+movement] = 'R';
    return movement;
}
```

Below is my superclass h file. It is initially has no variables in the ().

```
#ifndef ROBOTRACE_H
#define ROBOTRACE_H

using namespace std;

class robotRace {

      public:

       robotRace (); //constructor
       static const int rows = 5;
       static const int columns = 5;
       void printRace();
      protected:
       char track[rows][columns];
       char race[rows][columns]; //initial base for race floor

};// end superclass robotRace that should do no movement

#endif
```

This is where I initialized the constructor of superclass in robotRace.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "robotRace.h"

using namespace std;

robotRace :: robotRace() {

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
            {
                    if (i == 0)     //top boundary
                    {
                            track[i][j] = 'X';
                    }
                    else if (i == 4 && j < 4)   //bottom boundary
                    {
                            track[i][j] = 'X';
                    }
                    else if (i == 4 && j < 5)  //prints finish line
                    {
                            track[i][j] = 'F';
                    }
                    else if ((i >= 0 && i <= 4) && j == 0)   //left boundary
                    {
                            track[i][j] = 'X';
                    }
                    else
                    {
                            track[i][j] = ' ';
                    }
            }
    }

    race[0][0] = ' ';
}//end constructor
```

The issues or error shows on main.cpp where you see the robots[1] and etc. I couldn't get the .obj versions to work properly so I am trying to call them as a vector. The information in the () are mean't to connect to my postion function in the RandomRobot.cpp file. I guess this is my issue and I don't know how to get them to work yet.

```
vector < robotRace* > robots(3);
robotRace raceObj;

int seconds = 0;
static int ranNum = 0;
static int funNum = 0;
static int unpreNum = 0;
int rpos = 0;
int mpos = 0;
int upos = 0;

for (int i =0; i < rows; i++)
{
    for (int j=0; j < columns; j++){
            int k =0;
            while (k < columns)
            {
             robots[1] = new FunctionRobot (1, funNum);
             robots[2] = new RandomRobot (2, ranNum);
             robots[3] = new UnpredictedRobot (3, unpreNum);
//                randomObj.Rposition(1, ranNum);
//              functionObj.Mposition(0, funNum);
//            unpredictObj.Uposition(2, unpreNum);
            //Increment movements
```

Comment: Have you defined the the constructor robotRace() ?

Comment: Do we have to guess what the errors are? Is it a game?

Comment: I added the error in my title but was asked to remove it... I am adding it now and I added the initialize of robotRace

Comment: my main constructor doesn't have "int" in the () yet the error is stating I need them now?? This is why I am confused

Comment: The error is happening while compiling `main.cpp`, so its code should be part of your post.

Comment: The error is in main.cpp, yet you do not show main.cpp?

Comment: This is a common problem with your posts here so far. Please learn how to construct [testcases](http://sscce.org)!

Comment: I added my main portion. I am trying to get my movefunctions to connect. the variables in the () are suppose to connect to my functions and they are responding as my constructer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
robots[2] = new RandomRobot (2, ranNum);
```

I don't know what this is supposed to do but, since your `RandomRobot` constructor takes no arguments, it can't do it!

Comment: Ya I see that now. I am going to go back to my original code of RandomRobot randObj. format so that I can call the (2, ranNum) right. Back to the drawing board